# Error deploying Sidekiq to Ubuntu using Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, capistrano, sidekiq, capistrano3

I'm following the directions here to integrate Sidekiq with Capistrano on Ubuntu: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Deploying-to-Ubuntu

I'm having an issue with the Capistrano part.

I put this code at the end of `deploy.rb`:

```
# For capistrano 3
namespace :sidekiq do
  task :quiet do
    # Horrible hack to get PID without having to use terrible PID files
    puts capture("kill -USR1 $(sudo initctl status workers | grep /running | awk '{print $NF}') || :") 
  end
  task :restart do
    execute :sudo, :initctl, :restart, :workers
  end
end

after 'deploy:starting', 'sidekiq:quiet'
after 'deploy:reverted', 'sidekiq:restart'
after 'deploy:published', 'sidekiq:restart'
```

And I get this error when I run `cap production deploy`:

```
cap aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `capture' for main:Object
config/deploy.rb:67:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@project/gems/capistrano-3.2.1/lib/capistrano/dsl/task_enhancements.rb:12:in `block in after'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@project/gems/capistrano-3.2.1/lib/capistrano/dsl.rb:15:in `invoke'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@project/gems/capistrano-3.2.1/lib/capistrano/tasks/framework.rake:65:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@project/gems/capistrano-3.2.1/lib/capistrano/tasks/framework.rake:64:in `each'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@project/gems/capistrano-3.2.1/lib/capistrano/tasks/framework.rake:64:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@project/gems/capistrano-3.2.1/lib/capistrano/application.rb:15:in `run'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@project/gems/capistrano-3.2.1/bin/cap:3:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@project/bin/cap:23:in `load'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@project/bin/cap:23:in `<main>'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@project/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@project/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => sidekiq:quiet
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: #<NoMethodError: undefined method `capture' for main:Object>
```

Obviously, it's the capture function that's undefined, but what is the problem? Did I put the code in the right file `deploy.rb`? Do I need to require something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify which server to run the code on. For instance:

```
namespace :sidekiq do
  task :quiet do
    # Horrible hack to get PID without having to use terrible PID files
    on roles(:app) do
      puts capture("kill -USR1 $(sudo initctl status workers | grep /running | awk '{print $NF}') || :") 
    end
  end
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app) do
      execute :sudo, :initctl, :restart, :workers
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to require the sidekiq gem, or take a look at [capistrano with sidekiq integration](https://github.com/seuros/capistrano-sidekiq)

Comment: why is this downvoted? According to https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/71e523757e18cb2483703429613b268dd262415a/lib/sidekiq/web_helpers.rb the method is defined in the Sidekiq module, so requiring the module should fix it.

Comment: @NekoNova I tried requiring the module at the top of `deploy.rb` with `require 'sidekiq'`. `sidekiq` is already in my Gemfile. Still got `NoMethodError: undefined method 'capture' for main:Object`. Tried changing it to `Sidekiq.capture`, but that didn't work either. Are you sure the capture method is not this method: https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-DSL-Action-Inspection-Capture?

Comment: could also be. Does it work if you use the full module notation from Capistrano to call it ? And do you invoke the rake task with bundle exec?

Comment: @ill_always_be_a_warriors show me your entire error logs. I assume Capistrano's Application class was not initialized or something.

Comment: @seoyoochan Full error added to the question above.

Comment: `"kill -USR1 $(sudo initctl status workers | grep /running | awk '{print $NF}') || :"` is this working correctly on your terminal? that line was failed at line 5~8 on `https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/master/lib/capistrano/dsl/task_enhancements.rb`